# new to using classes in C

Tags: c

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

int numStudents;
int i = 0 ;
int sum;

printf("How many students are in your class? \n");
scanf("%d", &numStudents);

int grade[numStudents];


while ( i < numStudents ){
      scanf("%d", &grade[i]);
      printf("\n");
      i++;
      }

average(int grade[numStudents]);
printf("%d", &sum);     

}


int average(int x[y]){
    int sum;

    for (a=0; a<=y ;a++){
    sum = sum + x[a];
    }

    sum = sum / y;
    return sum;
}
```

I am asking what is wrong with my code.

Comment: and are you using classes in C, or using C in your class?

Comment: its my sleep or this post? something is not right.

Comment: You should check that `scanf()` succeeds.  You should have included `<stdio.h>` too.  If your compiler gives errors, you should read them, and add them to your question.  You should read them first, though.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, this

```
int average(int x[y]){           /* wrong */
int average(int x[], int y){     /* probably what you want */
```

And

```
average(int grade[numStudents]); /* totally wrong */
average(grade, numStudents);     /* might work */
```

There is an off-by-one errory in `average` that I'm not pointing out since it's homework. I urge other posters not to point it out.

Comment: And probably add the length of the table as another argument...

Comment: this isnt homework, im not sure how to make you believe me but its not

Comment: @programaholic This is the one sane thing you posted: you are right, I don't believe you. And even if it's not homework, you have to figure that one yourself.

Comment: @programaholic: Please do more work on figuring out the problem yourself, and supply more information on what exactly you're having problems with (platform, language, APIs, etc.) and stating what you're trying to do.

Comment: In C99, you might write: `int average(int num, int grade[static num])` with the length before the array argument.  You might omit the `static` too; it is a tad esoteric given the question.

Comment: @programaholic It looks and smells like homework, and your errors and approach here are very much like those of a beginning programming student. If it's not homework then what is it? To make people believe you, you could at least take a stab of explaining.